# draw png figure to tikz format

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use inkscape to trace bitmap to tex file, but the format is pspicture, I would like to use tikz format, any other tool can covert png to tikz? Or I need to draw it manually?

[image]

Comment: There's [`svg2tikz`](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz)

Comment: Or maybe https://code.google.com/archive/p/inkscape2tikz/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `svg2tikz` does [not yet work with Inkscape 1.0](https://github.com/xyz2tex/svg2tikz/issues/42).

Until this is fixed, I think the best option is to use the `tikz` library `svg.path`.

It still requires a bit of work, but is easier than converting all your paths to `tikz` paths.

Consider the following SVG file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   width="43.272217mm"
   height="38.881153mm"
   viewBox="0 0 43.272217 38.881153"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     id="layer1"
     transform="translate(-21.012752,-24.209217)">
    <path
       id="path839"
       style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m 35.191692,35.091655 -0.378794,11.672673 13.681705,2.121969 5.540123,-8.42804 z M 32.749265,24.209217 21.012752,40.845829 35.717567,63.090369 64.28497,50.77026 62.548425,32.255796 Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

We can pull out the path and draw it directly in a `tikzpicture` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=-1]
  \fill[even odd rule] svg "m 35.191692,35.091655 -0.378794,11.672673
    13.681705,2.121969 5.540123,-8.42804 z M 32.749265,24.209217
    21.012752,40.845829 35.717567,63.090369 64.28497,50.77026
    62.548425,32.255796 Z";
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You might have to fiddle with the scale (in particular the `yscale` must be negative), add translations, or add subsequent operations at a position referencing the current bounding box, but it's not too painful for simple drawings.

[image: output]